# Application Settings for Multiple C# Libraries in Mono (Linux)

Tags: c#, mono, settings

I have a project being ported to work on Linux under Mono.  The project includes multiple C# libraries, which have their own user-scoped, Application Settings (generated automatically via VS2008).  In the end, the project will run on .NET in Windows and Mono in Ubuntu 10.04.

When operating in Windows, Application Settings are stored in a single user.config file with separate Configuration Sections for each library:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="UserSettingsGroup ...>
      <section name="LibFoo.Properties.Settings" type="ClientSettingsSection ... />
      <section name="LibBar.Properties.Settings" type="ClientSettingsSection ... />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <userSettings>
    <LibFoo.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="strFoo" serializeAs="String">
        <value>An example string value.</value>
      </setting>
    </LibFoo.Properties.Settings>
    <LibBar.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="strBar" serializeAs="String">
        <value>An example string value.</value>
      </setting>
    </LibBar.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

In Ubuntu, a single user.config is created, however, I find that only one section is created for whichever library first calls Properties.Settings.Save(), and all libraries use that same section:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="UserSettingsGroup ... >
      <section name="LibFoo.Properties.Settings" type="ClientSettingsSection ... />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <userSettings>
    <LibFoo.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="strFoo" serializeAs="String">
        <value>An example string value.</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="strBar" serializeAs="String">
        <value>An example string value.</value>
      </setting>
    </LibFoo.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

This becomes particularly troubling when settings among the libraries have the same name.

Is this a bug in Mono, or do I need to change something for Mono to generate separate sections for my library's settings?

- Ubuntu v10.04
- mono-runtime v2.10.8
- Visual Studio 2008 Professional

Comment: if you have Libraries that consume or have the same name.. have you thought about fully qualifying the namespace or even better Aliasing..?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE - If I understand your suggestion, I think I may have misled you.  None of the libraries have the same name, but their Application Settings might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the same config name problem, you can try to put the configuration settings in the config file for each DLL. Your config file needs to have the name "MyDLL.dll.config" (assuming your DLL is named "MyDLL.dll") and be in the same folder as the DLL.

(never tested under mono)

To write in dll's config files:

You can make an Extension method "Save", and in this method use reflection to retrieve the Assembly name (Calling assembly, not current assembly), then use SaveAs to save the configuration. This way you have a method to save in dll config files.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in Mono.  The application still writes to the single .config file under ~/.local/share, and does not change the *.config files local to the assembly.  Good idea, though.

Comment: @walkingTarget: And instead of saving with the Save method, could you use SaveAs and save using "MyDLL.dll.config" ?
You can make an Extension method "Save", and in this method use reflection to retrieve the Assembly name (Calling assembly, not current assembly), then use SaveAs to save the configuration. This way you have a method to save in dll config files

Comment: The extension method has opened a lot of doors for a workaround solution.  Thanks for the suggestion.  If you could you add that info to your answer, I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: Done, Thank you. Happy that I could help you.